# creating a 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript

please i am new to javascript and i want to create a two dimensional array. this is the code i have:

```
var locations = new Array(track);

for(var j = 0; j < track; j++){         
    locations[j] = new Array();
    locations[j] = ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
}
```

when i try to output locations, i have only one row of tests. please what could be the problem, because i am expecting track rows of test.

thanks.

Comment: what is the track var?

Comment: Well, `locations[j] = new Array()` is redundant. Other than that, this looks ok to me provided `track` is an integer greater than 0

Comment: The problem may be your output code, so post that as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want something to print all the rows you have to keep you what you have already printed so you have to do something like this :

```
for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {   

         document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML =
         document.getElementById("myResults").innerHTML + locations[j] + "<br>";
}
```

You can see it there:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ba8TU/